# Maven local dependency authentication error

Tags: maven, netbeans, jsf-2

I have a `JSF` application that use `Primefaces`, where I've created a custom theme that `Primefaces` use for the presentation. The theme is placed in a `JAR` file that I have added as a local `Maven` dependency.

After months of not touching the code, I made some minor changes today. When trying to build the application, I get an error saying that it failed:

> Failed to read artifact descriptor for nivis2:nivis2:jar:2: could not transfer artifact... etc.

When trying to show `Artifact details` in `NetBeans` I get some more information:

> Error resolving project artifact: Could not transfer artifact
>   nivis2:nivis2:pom:2 from/to PrimeFaces-maven-lib
>   (http://repository.primefaces.org/): peer not authenticated for
>   project nivis2:nivis2:jar:2

POM:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>com.nivis</groupId>
    <artifactId>idre_mk2</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>war</packaging>

    <name>idre_mk2</name>

    <properties>
        <endorsed.dir>${project.build.directory}/endorsed</endorsed.dir>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-configuration</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-configuration</artifactId>
            <version>1.10</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.primefaces</groupId>
            <artifactId>primefaces</artifactId>
            <version>5.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>nivis2</groupId>
            <artifactId>nivis2</artifactId>
            <version>2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax</groupId>
            <artifactId>javaee-web-api</artifactId>
            <version>7.0</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jsoup</groupId>
            <artifactId>jsoup</artifactId>
            <version>1.7.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
            <version>1.7.12</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.mail</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.mail-api</artifactId>
            <version>1.5.4</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Shiro dependencies: -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.shiro</groupId>
            <artifactId>shiro-core</artifactId>
            <version>1.2.4</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.shiro</groupId>
            <artifactId>shiro-web</artifactId>
            <version>1.2.4</version>
            <!--<classifier>sources</classifier>-->
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-logging</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-logging</artifactId>
            <version>1.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-beanutils</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-beanutils</artifactId>
            <version>1.9.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.omnifaces</groupId>
            <artifactId>omnifaces</artifactId>
            <version>2.1</version>
            <!--<classifier>sources</classifier>-->
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.7</source>
                    <target>1.7</target>
                    <compilerArguments>
                        <endorseddirs>${endorsed.dir}</endorseddirs>
                    </compilerArguments>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.3</version>
                <configuration>
                    <failOnMissingWebXml>false</failOnMissingWebXml>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-dependency-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.6</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <phase>validate</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>copy</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <outputDirectory>${endorsed.dir}</outputDirectory>
                            <silent>true</silent>
                            <artifactItems>
                                <artifactItem>
                                    <groupId>javax</groupId>
                                    <artifactId>javaee-endorsed-api</artifactId>
                                    <version>7.0</version>
                                    <type>jar</type>
                                </artifactItem>
                            </artifactItems>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
    <repositories>
        <repository>
            <url>http://repository.primefaces.org/</url>
            <id>PrimeFaces-maven-lib</id>
            <layout>default</layout>
            <name>Repository for library PrimeFaces-maven-lib</name>
        </repository>
    </repositories>
</project>
```

Directory:

[image]

The `nivis2-2.pom.lastUpdated` file contains the following info:

```
#NOTE: This is an internal implementation file, its format can be changed without prior notice.
#Mon Aug 07 13:49:13 CEST 2017
default-http\://repository.primefaces.org/.lastUpdated=1502106553736
http\://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/.lastUpdated=1502105030633
http\://repository.primefaces.org/.error=Could not transfer artifact nivis2\:nivis2\:pom\:2 from/to PrimeFaces-maven-lib (http\://repository.primefaces.org/)\: sun.security.validator.ValidatorException\: PKIX path building failed\: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException\: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
```

I haven't really changed anything and I'm not sure how to interpret the error message - does it try to copy my JAR-file to an external `Primefaces` repository? Why now all of the sudden?

Regardless. I only need to be able to use the custom `Primefaces` theme and maybe there are better ways of doing that than this?

Comment: This is nor a PrimeFaces library. It is not in that repository. Most likely ypur maven settings.xml changed or this library was in your local repo in the past and it currently is not

Comment: For the error in your edited question, search the internet... has a Q/A already

Comment: I've been unable to find an answer when searching the Internet, perhaps I didn't understand that I looked at the answer - can you point me to the page in question?

Answer (score 0):

Which maven goal are you executing?
If you run `mvn clean deploy`, use `mvn clean install` instead.

The install goal will put the built artifact in your local repository under your .m2 folder in your user home, the deploy goal is used to deploy your artifact to a remote repository.

Comment: Looking at the config in `Netbeans` it says `install` under `Execute goals`, so I believe it's correct.

Comment: Did you add any plugins to your pom.xml?

Comment: I'll add the POM to the question - there are some plugins specified

Comment: Ah ok, the pom.xml might help :)
The nivis artifact, is provided by you, right? Did you build that before? Can you check your Maven Repository Folder (Default: [USER_HOME]/.m2/repsoitory/nivis2/nivis2/2) there needs to be a jar inside called nivis2-2.jar

Comment: Yes, that is the JAR with the custom `Primefaces theme` and it's available in the local repository. It has been working ok before and I have not made any changes that explains this behavior. I've also removed the whole `.m2` folder and downloaded every dependency, added the local dependency again (which works fine) - but when trying to build it fails if I include the local `JAR` dependency.

Comment: Sounds really weird to me, it really seems that maven is trying to upload your artifact to the PrimeFaces repository. Did you also try to build the project from command line? And which maven version are you using?

Comment: I updated `Netbeans` to the latest version and recreated the POM, which solved the problem. Sadly I couldn't narrow down what exactly caused the problem though. Thank you for taking your time to help me out!

Comment: Glad that you could solve your issue and thanks for sharing!

Answer (score 0):

Thank you all for helping me. I got it working in the end through installing the latest version of `Netbeans` and re-creating the POM. I don't know what or both of this solved the problem or exactly what was causing it in the first place, but now it works.

Once again, thanks for taking your time looking in to my problem.